# Creating a diagram using LaTex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am still very new to learning how to use LaTex and I was wondering how I would be able to create a diagram such as this using LaTex software. As a side note, I havent been able to install the smartdiagram package in TexWorks so I am using tikz.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! You can use `tikz-cd`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows={-latex}]
(K_1\to P_1) \arrow[r,bend left]& (K_2\to P_2) \arrow[r,bend left]
& (K_3\to P_3)
\arrow[l,bend left,start anchor={[xshift=2em]},end anchor={[xshift=-2em]}]\\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I will play around with the code to see if I can get a firmer understanding on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tikz-cd`, as already suggested; the trick used here is to add dummy entries.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1em]
(K_1 \arrow[r] & P_1) \arrow[rr,bend left,start anchor={[xshift=-1em]},end anchor={[xshift=1em]}]
&&
(K_2 \arrow[r] & P_2) \arrow[rr,bend left,start anchor={[xshift=-1em]},end anchor={[xshift=1em]}]
&&
(K_3 \arrow[r] & P_3) \arrow[llll,bend left]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]